# Can I use graphics.RotateTransform() without these artifacts?

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, rotation, gdi+

I'm implementing a colour picker component as described in this [seminal article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164113.aspx).

As you can see, I've got the basics sorted:

[image: Working colour wheel]

One of the requirements however, is the ability to have the colour wheel rotated by an arbitrary amount. Thinking this would be easy, I some arithmetic to the mouse location -> colour value code and the following code to the bit that actually paints the wheel:

```
newGraphics.TranslateTransform((float)this.Radius, (float)this.Radius);
newGraphics.RotateTransform((float)this.offset);
newGraphics.TranslateTransform((float)this.Radius * -1, (float)this.Radius * -1);
```

Unfortunately, rotating the bitmap like this actually produces this:

[image: Broken colour wheel after rotation]

Note the artefacts that appear either side of the centre.

Am I using the wrong approach? Or is there a way to get rid of these nasty rips?

Comment: That's some pretty dirty tearing. One alternative to rotating the wheel itself would be to pass the rotation amount to whatever function is filling in the colors on the circle, and then have that adjust the color wheel accordingly without needing to do a transform.

Comment: I can't recreate the issue you describe right now. You can try set Graphics.PixelOffsetMode to PixelOffsetMode.Half. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @aardvarkk That sounds promising - I'll have a look at other options.

Comment: @Lucas Just tried this, but it didn't change anything. I even tried on the "HighQuality" setting. No dice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code from that Microsoft example, I made the following change to the `UpdateDisplay` method by adding a matrix and setting the `RotateAt` method.

```
private void UpdateDisplay() {
  // Update the gradients, and place the 
  // pointers correctly based on colors and 
  // brightness.

  using (Brush selectedBrush = new SolidBrush(selectedColor)) {      
    using (Matrix m = new Matrix()) {
      m.RotateAt(35f, centerPoint);
      g.Transform = m;
      // Draw the saved color wheel image.
      g.DrawImage(colorImage, colorRectangle);
      g.ResetTransform();
    }

    // Draw the "selected color" rectangle.
    g.FillRectangle(selectedBrush, selectedColorRectangle);

    // Draw the "brightness" rectangle.
    DrawLinearGradient(fullColor);
    // Draw the two pointers.
    DrawColorPointer(colorPoint);
    DrawBrightnessPointer(brightnessPoint);
  }
}
```

It rotated the wheel 35 degrees (although the color selection was off now by, well, 35 degrees since I didn't mess with all the code) and it didn't produce any tearing.

Not 100% sure this is the answer (but too long for a comment), so maybe this is helpful.

Comment: I've no idea why doing it this way should be different, but the ripping is now gone. Thanks Lars!